# is it a group homomorphism?$f:(\mathbb{R}^*,\cdot)\to(\{-1,+1,\},\cdot)$ defined by $f(x)={x\over |x|}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$f:(\mathbb{R}^*,\cdot)\to(\{-1,+1,\},\cdot)$ defined by $f(x)={x\over |x|}$ , is it a group homomorphism? does it make sense?I am confused to see the question in a past year question paper.

I know that $f$ would be homomorphism if we just send negative reals to $-1$ and positive reals to $+1$

Comment: You're identifying the positives with $+1$ and negatives with $-1$, do you see it?

Comment: You probably mean $(\{-1,1\},\cdot)$, not $\{-1,1,.\}$.

Answer (score 4):

The map makes sense, because $f(x) \in \{-1, 1\}$ for every $x$, recalling that $0 \notin \mathbb{R}^*$. To check whether it is a group homomorphism, it is best to just do it directly:

$$f(x \cdot y) = \frac{xy}{|xy|} = \frac{x}{|x|} \frac{y}{|y|} = f(x) f(y)$$

as desired.